# Google Cloud: Unable to create new projects on a new account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've just signed up to a new account on Google Cloud, but I can't create any new projects in the Developers Console. I've added a billing credit card, but every time I try to create any new project (blank, Hello World, prebuilt solutions), I get a generic error message in Activities which states a status of `Forbidden` with no further information.

Has anyone encountered this before? The docs aren't very enlightening - even some tips on how to diagnose my problem would be helpful.

Comment: This is a case for Google support. Even if they listed SF as a resource to get help, that's something only Google can help you with.

Comment: @Sven I agree, but I can't even put in a support request without being able to start a new project. Their own support directs me to SF and states that they sponsor tags here, so this is the only option I can see to (possibly) get the case in front of Google staff eyes.

Comment: I've never seen anyone claiming to be from Google answering one of those questions with the sponsored tags. Maybe on SO, but not here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved my own problem. I realised that the Google account I was trying to use for Cloud is managed by my Google Apps for Work account; I needed to add Google Developer Console as a service available to members of my organisation.